# 'À avoir eu' : what kind of form is this?

Tags: grammaire, verbes, prépositions, auxiliaires, infinitif

I have seen one form of using *avoir*, recently, like this: **à avoir eu**.

I forgot the phrase itself, but, for example in this phrase I just found in Google:

> Les jeunes de l’OM sont 2 sur 14 à avoir eu le bac cette année.

What kind of form is it? When/Where it supposed to be used?..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This *à* is a preposition and is not part of the verb form. This sentence is based on the construction “***être*** [un certain nombre] **à**” like in:

> Ils **sont** 3 sur 4 **à** regarder la télé plus de trois heures par jour.
>   Ils **sont** plus de la moitié **à** regretter son départ.

This preposition is then followed by a verb in infinitive form. In French an infinitive can be given an “accomplished aspect” (*aspect révolu*), which is formed using the appropriate auxiliary verb (it depends on the main verb) and the past participle. In your case “*avoir*” becomes “*avoir eu*”. Other examples:

> Elle se rappelle *avoir marché* sur les Champs Élysées.
>   Il pensait *avoir résolu* le problème.
>   Ils croient *être allés* sur Mars.

And in passive form:

> Il croyait *avoir été compris*.

Comment: why there is no 'à' here: Il pensait (à) avoir résolu le problème. ?

Comment: I still do not understand when to put 'à' and when not to.

Comment: @ses Dictionary. This is the same reason you cannot know by looking at it whether an English verb is [catenative](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catenative_verb) (whether it takes "to" after it or not) or not. That's a feature of the word itself in the same way that its meaning or its spelling are.

Comment: For 'catenative' verbs in English (as I understand) we can say: It began to rain = It began raining. But could we use this rule for French as well, like: Ils sont 3 sur 4 à regarder la télé  = Ils sont 3 sur 4 *en regardant* la télé.. ?

Comment: @ses: your example is not a parallel construction. Consider instead: ils étaient trois à avoir résolu le problème. Also consider: Il pensait avoir regardé la télé. (Sorry for the contrived sentences.)

Comment: [il pensait avoir eu un "flat tire" = il pansait qu'il a eu 'flat tire' ?] Is there any difference in sense of meaning and tense ?

Comment: "*Il pensait qu'il **avait** eu un pneu crevé*" would be similar to "*il pensait avoir eu un pneu crevé*". But shorter is better in this case.

Comment: @ses notice that "Il pensait à résoudre le problème" and "Il pensait résoudre le problème" don't have exactly the same meaning. The later somehow implies that he has already tried something to solve the problem but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You can translate it word by word to “to have had”, and as far as I can tell, it has the same meaning.

*Avoir eu* is called the [**past infinitive**](http://french.about.com/od/grammar/a/pastinfinitive.htm) of *avoir*, and “indicates an action that occurred before the action of the main verb, but only when the subject of both verbs is the same.”

The second part of it is *“être quelques-uns à faire quelque chose”*, which does not translate very well in English, but means “those who did this (or to whom this happened) were, say, a few”.

Here, “they were 2 out of 14 to pass the exam” seems not so poorly said. (Or “… to have received their diploma”, to stick to the french construction)